# BouncyCastle AlgorithmIdentifier

Tags: rsa, bouncycastle

How can i create a new instance of `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier` of RSA OAEP? in order to be able to use it here:

```
JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(java.security.cert.X509Certificate recipientCert, org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier algorithmIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with current BouncyCastleVersions you can use a constant from `org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers`

```
AlgorithmIdentifier algorithmIdentifier = new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSAES_OAEP);
```

Comment: Even if i've already solved my problem, but will keep this in my mind for next time have to use this API.

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as creating object from string representation of RSA with OAEP [oid](http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.1.7)

```
AlgorithmIdentifier id = AlgorithmIdentifier.getInstance("1.2.840.113549.1.1.7");
```

in recent versions of BouncyCastle >1.50 this API has been removed and getInstance takes only ASN1Sequence and AlgorithmIdentifier. So there is no option, but to use constructor:

```
AlgorithmIdentifier id = new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSAES_OAEP);
```

Comment: Results in error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: java.lang.String`

Comment: Yes, constructor with a string parameter got deprecated and ASN1Sequencemust be used instead, which is pretty useless.

Comment: This really helped me:
AlgorithmIdentifier.getInstance(DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA256withRSA")